# How to find all the options supported by a command?

Tags: dart

Docs says:

> Run `"dart help <command>"` for more information about a command.

But, if I run

```
dart help run
```

It doesn't show `--enable-experiment` option, so how can I find all the options for a command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to see a more complete list of what you can do. I cannot guarantee the list are complete:

```
dart help -v run
```

Comment: A little side question. You can also do `dart run -v -h` but why can't you do `dart run -vh` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20106212/6618622)

Comment: Well, it really depends on the program if it supports concatenated arguments. It is not something you get for free as your program will just see the argument (e.g. `-hv` or `-h -v`) when it gets it from the OS.

Comment: Alright, I thought it was universal sort of thing like instead of `--foo` you can always write `-f`

Comment: It is indeed a rather standard behavior and you could argue that an issue could be filled on the Dart SDK bug tracker. But it is really not a problem for me personally and I don't care enough to create an issue about it. :)

Comment: Ahh, thanks for clearing it up. Anyways, I really need to work on my English, instead of "universal sort of thing", it should be "standard behavior" haha.